# (C#.NET-WPF) Keep all focus on application window

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I am developing a program that starts when the Desktop loads and gives a few "quick access" options to start the computer with. I have the window on Topmost, and the window is always Activated, but I want the program to restrict all input to it's window. Now, as I know this is a controversial topic, I must clarify that this application is for **my personal use only** and will not be distributed. I have seen a few questions posted all over the web but most of them are outdated (9-11 years old) and I believe reading about MS removing focus stealing a while back. Is there any way to do this?

My code:

```xml
<!-- In the window's XAML tag -->
...
 WindowStyle="None"
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
        WindowState="Normal"
        ResizeMode="NoResize"
        Topmost="True"
...
```

```cs
// In the window's C# script
 void window_Deactivated(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Activate();
        }
```

Comment: You could try creating a transparent full screen child window behind your main window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MS has removed focus stealing (from only 3rd party programs apparently), so this is not possible.

What you can do is create a child window behind the main one, and when the window loads, load the window.

XAML for the child window:

```xml
Name = "Backdrop"
WindowState = "Maximized"
```

C# for the main window:

```cs
void window_Loaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Run(new Backdrop());
    }
```